# Defining a relationship from one end works, but defining it from the other end causes an error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Why does the first line after calling base in OnModelCreating cause an error? The commented line that throws causes this error:

The expression 'x => value(Blog.Services.Db).ContentItems' is not a valid property expression. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'.
Parameter name: propertyAccessExpression

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder mb)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(mb);
        mb.Entity<ContentGroup>().HasMany(x => ContentItems).WithOne(x => x.ContentGroup).HasForeignKey(x => x.ContentGroupID);  // same effect as following line but throws an error
        //mb.Entity<ContentItem>().HasOne(x => x.ContentGroup).WithMany(x => x.ContentItems).HasForeignKey(x => x.ContentGroupID); // same effect as previous line but works

    }
```

ContentGroup:

```
public class ContentGroup
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int SiteID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Sequence { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public virtual Site Site { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ContentItem> ContentItems { get; set; }
}
```

ContentItem:

```
public class ContentItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public int ContentGroupID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PublishDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModifyDate { get; set; }
    public string ChangeFrequency { get; set; }
    public decimal? Priority { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string MenuText { get; set; }
    public string URI { get; set; }
    public string Abstract { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; }
    public bool AllowComments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual ContentGroup ContentGroup { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MenuContentItem> MenuContentItems { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>In the first statement the `HasForeignKey()` method reflects to `ContentGroup` entity not the `ContentItem` entity. `ContentGroup` entity does not have `ContentGroupId` property that's why it does not work.</strike>

**UPDATE:**

> The expression 'x => value(Blog.Services.Db).ContentItems' is not a valid property expression. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. Parameter name: propertyAccessExpression

According to the exception message it occured because in the first statement you have `.HasMany(x => ContentItems)` but it should be `.HasMany(x => x.ContentItems)`.

Comment: Gabor, thanks for your answer but unfortunately it is not correct.  The HasForeignKey method takes a ContentItem as a parameter.  If it took  ContentGroup it would not even build.

Comment: @Sam, I updated my answer considering the exception message in your post.